# Disable products programmatically based on values

Tags: products, stock

I have a problem. I need to disable products if they are in category ID 154 and have a quantity of less then 1.

I use the backorder function but these products should not be able to backorder. How can I solve this?

Another way can be to add a special attribute to the products and when they go quantity=0 they should get disabled. Or they get the value "Not in stock"

But how can I solve this in a good clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?php   
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '600M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin'); 
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'));
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('eq' => '4'));
            foreach($collection as $_data)
            {
                    $productCat = $_data->getCategoryIds();
                     $stock =  Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_data);
                    $productqty =  $stock->getQty();
                    if(in_array('154',$productCat) && intval($productqty) < 1){
                    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                    $productUpdate = $productModel->load($_data->getId());
                    $productUpdate->setStatus(2);
                    $productUpdate->save();
                }
            }

    ?>
```

Comment: This code should be in a cron job executing a php file?
What does it do?

1. checking if an product is in category id 154 AND if quantity<1
2. Set status = 2 which means disabled?

Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: you can place this file in your magento root directory and run it from url exp:- www.yoursite.com/filename.php no need to set cron job for it.

Comment: you can change condition according to your need.in "IF" condition i have checked if products belong to category 154 and its qty is less than 1 then product will disable.

Comment: Solution works great. Thank you.
Now I have a cron job executing the php file every 30 min

Answer (score -1):

If the products are configured to use stock management, there is an attribute "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock".

[image]

Set it to 0, and Magento will automatically set the item to be out of stock when the stock reaches 0.